# Typo3 v9 how to query my extension with specific url?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

im in the process of developing a Typo3 extension and i want to access the data of this extension from a static URL.
The extension will be used in multiple systems and i want to query them like so: https://example.com/myextension

the specific URL slug is not relevant. The goal is that i dont have to configure in every of the systems the specific url where i
can reach the data gathered by my extension to summarize them all in a dashboard overview.

So my question is how can i set that my extension controller action is triggered with the call of a specific url?
If there are better ways to do this, please let me know

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Middleware https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html that calls your action for a specific URL.

Or you could add a real page with a given slug and your plugin with an Upgrade Wizard https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/UpdateWizards/Creation.html or Extension update script https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/UpdateWizards/ExtUpdateFile.html.
For the nice URL you would use a routeEnhancer in the Site Config.

---

If this is something like a webservice where you need control over the HTTP verbs or implement OAuth, I would go with 1.

For something like a landing page I would go with 2. Also to expose an Extbase plugin action.

Comment: Thanks for your great input! Im not the best with ExtBase and Typo3, could you show me an example where a middleware intercepts a HTTP request to a specific url and returns a controller action?

Comment: I think the documentation on MiddleWares should get you going. If you encounter a problem along the way, open a new question.